# How to use External option in Texture painting?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

How to use this part in texture painting? I pressed "quick edit", I was transferred to a separate graphics editor - Photoshop - where I painted the texture. What's next? How to project what is drawn?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1- Choosing the resolution of the projected image - "Screen Grab image"

2- Select the desired angle in the viewport

3- Click "Quick Edit"

4- it throws us into the program for 2D editing (important - check that the path to "Image Editor". Path - Preferences > File Paths > Applications > Image Editor). We draw and edit the image any way we want, then (importantly) we merge everything into one layer and save it.

5- Then in Blender press the "Apply" button.